# Get substring from string with grep command

Tags: shell, grep

I have the following pattern of a string:

```
"METHOD URL VERSION"
```

example `"GET /someurl/resource.html HTTP/1.1"`

How can I get the url from this string with grep.

I did the following(assuming that string contains in f.txt)

```
cat f.txt | grep -P '[^(( )|(\")|(HTTP\/\d\.\d)|(GET)|(POST))]+' -o
```

but it gives me such an output

```
someurl
resource
html
```

How can I retrieve /someurl/resource.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
grep -o "\/.* "
```

ok, if you have the pattern:

"somestring1withoutspaces somestring2withoutspaces somestring3withoutspaces" then both of these works:

```
grep -o " .* " 
awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: url can start with http and with www or simply the name of the file like image.png